# Implementing ceil function without using if-else

Tags: python, algorithm, ceil

I just wanted to know that is there a way of implementing ceil function without using if-else?
With if-else `(for a/b)` it can be implemented as:

```
if a%b == 0:
    return(a/b)
else:
    return(a//b + 1)
```

Comment: `from math import ceil`?

Comment: @Blender: I want to do it without using the inbuilt ceil function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this should work if they are integers (I guess you have a rational number representation):

```
a/b + (a%b!=0)
```

Otherwise, replace `a/b` with `int(a/b)`, or, better, as suggested below `a//b`.

Comment: `a // b` would be better than `int(a / b)`.

Answer (score 10):

Simplest would be.

```
a//b + bool(a%b)
```

And just for safety,

```
b and (a//b + bool(a%b))
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

```
-(-a//b)
```

Perhaps the simplest?

========================

*Edited per @Gilles's comment:

for an integer n,

```
floor(x)=n for x in [n, n+1)
ceil(y)=n+1 for y in (n, n+1]
```

So, `floor(-y)=-n-1 for -y in [-n-1, -n)`,

and `ceil(y)=-floor(-y)=n+1 for y in (n, n+1]`

In Python, `floor(a/b) = a//b`.
Thus `ceil(a/b) = -(-a//b)`

Comment: Only if  by “simple” you mean concise but hardly understandable ...